# Kivy launcher warning message

Tags: kivy

My script is usable on pc, but from kivy launcher I obtain warning message, which is caused property callback function.

```
filechooser   = ObjectProperty

def __init__(self,inst_parent, **kwargs):
    super(FileOpen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        . . .
    self.filechooser.bind(path = self.on_path_select)
        . . .

def on_path_select(self, inst, val):
    . . .
    . . .
    return
```

Text of warning messge:

```
[WARNING           ] stderr:     self.fiopen = FileOpen(self)
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/storage/emulated/0/kivy/TestFilechooser_2/file_open.py", line 163, in __init__
[WARNING           ] stderr:     self.filechooser.bind(path = self.on_path_select)
[WARNING           ] stderr: TypeError: descriptor 'bind' of 'kivy.properties.Property' object needs an argument
```

Which argument do I have to use? Thank You for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration `filechooser = ObjectProperty` makes no sense, it's just the ObjectProperty object and not a proper property declaration. You should write `filechooser = ObjectProperty()` at class level.

Comment: Thank You! I am realLy blind.